# Passing a parameter to CreateThread

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, parameter-passing, createthread

I am having a problem passing a class reference as the parameter to the ThreadProc in a call to CreateThread. Here is a sample program that demonstrates the problem I am having:

```
program test;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils, Windows, Dialogs;

type
    TBlah = class
        public
        fe: Integer;
    end;

function ThreadProc(param: Pointer) : DWORD;
begin
    ShowMessage(IntToStr(TBlah(param).fe));

    Result := 0;
end;

var
    tID: DWORD;
    handle: THandle;
    b: TBlah;
begin
    b := TBlah.Create;
    b.fe := 54;

    handle := CreateThread(nil, 0, @ThreadProc, Pointer(b), 0, tID);

    WaitForSingleObject(handle, INFINITE); 
end.
```

The call to `ShowMessage` pops up a message box that has something like `245729105` in it, not `54` like I expect.

This is probably just a basic misunderstanding of how Delphi works, so could someone please tell me how to get this working properly?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem here is that your thread function has the wrong calling convention. You need to declare it with the `stdcall` convention:

```
function ThreadProc(param: Pointer) : DWORD; stdcall;
```

[image]

---

Having said that, it would be more idiomatic to just use a `TThread` descendant which handles the OOP to C function back to OOP transitioning for you.  That would look like this:

```
type
  TBlah = class(TThread)
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
  public
    fe: Integer;
  end;

procedure TBlah.Execute;
begin
  ShowMessage(IntToStr(fe));
end;

var
  b: TBlah;

begin
  b := TBlah.Create(True);
  b.fe := 42;
  b.Start;
  b.WaitFor;
end.
```

Incidentally, does anyone know why Windows.pas declares `TFNThreadStartRoutine` as `TFarProc` rather than a proper typed function pointer?

Comment: `b.fe := 42;`, don't forget the `:`  :)

Comment: @Kokonotsu Any particular reason for not using `TThread`? As for the `=` vs `:=`, guess I've been doing too much P/Invoke today!

Comment: A lot of typing, and a *screenshot*... Fast you are!

Comment: @Sertac Thx! Thing is, I need a couple more accepts, I'm desperate. Slipping down the rankings this week!!  ;-)

Comment: @Sertac Just my obsessive personality!!  ;-)

Comment: @David: FYI, I have never seen anyone at 332 points before: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/delphi/topusers

Comment: @Andreas I was more thinking of this one: http://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/week/stackoverflow

Answer (score 9):

You're forgetting the `stdcall` directive.

```
function ThreadProc(param: Pointer) : DWORD; stdcall;
```

Answer (score 1):

And don't use `Pointer` cast in:

```
handle := CreateThread(nil, 0, @ThreadProc, **Pointer**(b), 0, tID);
```

`b` is already a `Pointer` (a `Class`, which is an `Object` `Pointer`)